# M and N are manifolds and $f: M \to N$ is injective immersion, M is compact then...

Tags: analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my assignment on smooth manifolds and I am struck on it.

> Let $f: M \to N$ be an injective immersion, where M and N are manifolds. If M is compact, show that f(M) is a submanifold of N. Give examples to show that the result need not be true if

(a) M is not compact but all other assumptions hold.

(b) f is not injective but all other assumptions hold.

Now f is injective, df is injective and M is compact. Now to prove that f(M) is a submanifold I need to prove that: Let $p\in f(M)$ which means that p =f(m) for some $m \in M$ , I need to prove the existence of a chart $(U,\phi)$  containing p such that $\phi(U\cap S)$ is an open subset of $.

As $f(M)\in N$ so there always exists a chart containing P, but how can I show that $\phi(U\cap S)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. I am not able to think how to use injectivity of f and df and probably that is one of the reason why I couldn't find any counterexamples (a) and (b).

Comment: It is enough to show that if $f$ is a closed map, then it is an embedding (with the given assumptions of it being an injective immersion). Now, if $M$ is compact, is $f$ closed?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I think it is because space is haursdorff as it is manifold.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Aniruddha Deshmukh says, when $M$ is compact, $f$ is closed, so it's an embedding. A classical exercise/proposition is a continuous map from compact space to $T_2$(Hausdorff) space is closed.

For (a), try to consider topologist curves;

For (b), there're many examples, like Klein Bottle.

---

For all closed set $A$ in $M,$ $A$ is compact as $M$ is compact. Countinuous map maps compact sets to compact sets, so $f(A)$ is compact. Then $f(A)$ is closed in $N$ as $N$ being a manifold is Hausdorff. Thus $f^{-1}:f(M)\rightarrow M$ is countinuous, where $f(M)$ is equipped with subspace topology.

Combined with the fact that $f$ is injective, $f:M\rightarrow f(M)$ is a homeomorphism. Then for every point $p\in f(M),$ there exists a chart $(U,\varphi)$ containing $p$ such that $\varphi(S\cap U)$ is the intersection of a $k$-dimensional plane with $\varphi(U).$ (look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submanifold - Embedded submanifolds. One needs **Constant Rank Theorem** to prove that.)

Then $\varphi(U\cap S)=\varphi(U)\cap \mathbb{R}^k$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^k,$ since the topology of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is same with the subspace topology induced from $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: can you please write detailed answer?

Comment: @Evan I've edited my answer.